# removeBackView() not working in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

**JS code**

```
        console.log('Login Success');
        $ionicHistory.removeBackView();
```

I am trying to stop to get the login view after login. But even I was logged in, if I click on back arrow of the browser, I am getting the login page. But Once I logged in I should get home page if I click on back arrow. `.removeBackView()` is not working properly. Please help me.
Even `$ionicHistory disableBack` also not working

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem. Putting `removeBackView()` in the next state didn't work. So instead I added this to the previous state, right before  `$location.path( '/app/myFirstPage' )`

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions( {
    disableBack : true
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same type of problem so use another concept, I think its help you.

```
     if ($state.current.name == "app.home" || $state.current.name == "login") {
      $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: "Confirm",
        template: "Want to exit?"
      }).then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
          navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
      });
    } else {
      navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
```

Comment: in that case we are going to close the app. But we shouldn't right